# Why task is done when first element in the future list is true?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm little confused with tasks in Java multithreading.
Namely, I've 15 objects, which implements Callable and i'm submitting it by ExecutorService. Each Callable has its own progress bar with is updating in for loop with setProgress method.
I want to show 3 of 15 callables which will finish their job in first, second and third position by getting their names and setting it to labels on my scene. Of course each callable has different working time.

I created Task and i'm starting it in new thread and iterating over list of future tasks from my ExecutorService.
The problem is that my labels aren't visible until first element of the future list is true (until first thread is finished). I have really no idea why and i would be very grateful for your help.

```
public void startButtonClicked() {
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 3) {
                for (Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
                    try {
                        if (future.get() == true && i == 0) {
                            labelFirst.setVisible(true);
                            i++;
                        }

                        if (future.get() == true && i == 1) {
                            labelSecond.setVisible(true);
                            i++;
                        }

                        if (future.get() == true && i == 2) {
                            labelThird.setVisible(true);
                            i++;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    for (Callable c : callables) {
        futures.add(executorService.submit(c));
    }
    new Thread(task).start();

    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

In my ideal solution each label will become visible when their callable will finish, so labelSecond should appear some time after labelFirst.
It's my call method in my callable:

```
public Boolean call() {
    double raceTime = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(45.0, 60.0);

    try {
        for (double i = 0; i < raceTime; i += 0.01) {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
            progressBar.setProgress(i / raceTime);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

EDIT:
With checking future.isDone() and little changes it works as i wished.

```
public void startButtonClicked() {
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 3) {
                    i = 0;
                    for (Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
                        if (future.isDone() == true) i++;

                        if (i == 1) {
                            labelFirst.setVisible(true);
                            labelFirstCyclistName.setVisible(true);
                        }

                        if (i == 2) {
                            labelSecond.setVisible(true);
                            labelSecondCyclistName.setVisible(true);
                        }

                        if (i == 3) {
                            labelThird.setVisible(true);
                            labelThirdCyclistName.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        for (Cyclist c : cyclists) {
            futures.add(executorService.submit(c));
        }
        new Thread(task).start();

        executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what the code is supposed to be doing, but know that `Future.get` is a _blocking_ call. The method won't return until the `Future`'s task has completed either exceptionally (in which case an exception is thrown) or normally (in which case the value is returned).

Comment: Also, you are calling `setVisible` on a background thread. You must only modify GUI state on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. You can do this with `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: Should I call this task which is checking Future List in Platform.runLater? Or updateing progressbars?

Comment: You should only wrap the code modifying the GUI in `Platform.runLater` (see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)). Note that `Task` has properties/methods for communicating with the GUI in this manner (e.g. `updateProgress`, `updateMessage`, etc...). They not only run the updates on the _JavaFX Application Thread_ but they also coalesce updates to avoid flooding the FX thread with too much work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that my labels aren't visible until first element of
>   the future list is true (until first thread is finished). I have
>   really no idea why and i would be very grateful for your help.

---

According to the documentation of [Future#get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

> **Waits** if necessary **for the computation to complete**, and then retrieves
>   its result.

---

Here is your code - pay special attention to a line containing `future.get()`:

```
public Void call() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
            for (Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
                try {
                    if (future.get() == true && i == 0) {
```

During the first iteration of the loop the first future is retrieved  from `futures`, and then `future.get()` stops the execution of the loop and waits (holds) until execution of this first future (the first thread) will finish and will return a result.
Then the loop continues and `LabelX..setVisible(true);` are called making labels visible.

Comment: I see, that make sense - i was waiting in future.get(). Name of the method has totally misleaded me and it's my fault because i didn't check it in documentation.
Now with checking future.isDone() its work pretty well. Thank you.